# Analytics - Multiple List Widgets and Raw Data Tables - how to filter on both?

Tags: json, analytics, saql

I have a dashboard with two list widgets (Account and Opportunity) and two raw data tables (Opportunity Detail and Order Detail).

I have used SAQL to group data and then populate the first table (Order Detail) based on the selection from the first list (Account) - using a selection binding, and the second list (Opportunity) to populate the second table (Opportunity Detail) - also using a selection binding.

What I am trying to do now, is when a selection is made from the Opportunity List, i need the Sales Order Detail table to update based on that selection. Can someone help me with the SAQL code for this?

Here is my current code:

> "pigql": "q = load \"ds_SODetailV2\";
>   q = filter q by >'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_otype__c' == \"a6490000000CaTeAAK\" && 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_cancelled__c' == \"false\"; q = filter q by 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_account__c.Name' == {{value(selection(AccountSelector))}};
>   q = filter q by 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_opportunity__c.Name' == {{value(selection(OpportunitySelector))}};
>   q = foreach q generate 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_order__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_orderdate__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_intcomment__c';
>   q = group q by ('rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_order__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_orderdate__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_intcomment__c');
>   q = foreach q generate 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_order__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_orderdate__c', 'rstk__soline_sohdr__c.rstk__sohdr_intcomment__c'"